# Fill pattern to excel cell using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel, design-patterns

How to fill a pattern to excel cell?

Based on few posts on this forum, I tried to use following, but no success so far.

a)

```
oWB1.Worksheets(i).Cells(7, 3).Interior.PatternIndex = 5
```

b)

```
Dim style As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Style
style = oWB1.Styles.Add("Style1")
style.Interior.Pattern = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPattern.xlPatternSolid
oWB1.Worksheets(i).Cells(7, 3).Style = "Style1"
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This (Excel VSTO) code works:

```
Dim rng As Range = activeSheet.Range(1,1)
rng.Style = "Calculation"
```

"Calculation" is the name of the style.